# notation confusion

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, compiling, cuda

Trying to troubleshoot an error I'm getting (trying to run a program that uses nvidia's cuda),the CUDA getting started guide says:

> Set up the development environment by modifying the PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH variables:
>
> ```
> $ export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.1/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
> $ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.1/lib64\
>                      ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
> ```

Link: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-quick-start-guide/index.html#ixzz553mlsUKP

Am I supposed to replace one of the "PATH"s with the actual path?
Does "$" or curly brackets mean I should replace the example with my own path?

I'm very new to Linux in general, thanks in advance for your time and patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you should type it verbatim (with the exception of the leading `$`, which is just meant to indicate your shell prompt).

The sequence `${PATH:+:${PATH}}` is a *parameter expansion* - it just happens to be a tricky one to parse because one of the `:`s is part of the expansion syntax, while the other one is literal.

The basic syntax is `${parameter:+word}` which as explained in [BashGuide: Parameter Expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion) means

> If 'parameter' is null or unset, nothing is substituted, otherwise
>   'word' (which may be an expansion) is substituted.

In the above context, *parameter* is `PATH` and *word* is `:${PATH}`. So if `PATH` is empty or unset (which is very unlikely BTW), then the export becomes just

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.1/bin
```

whereas if `PATH` is non-empty, it becomes

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.1/bin:$PATH
```

i.e. prepends `/usr/local/cuda-9.1/bin` to your existing path, with the obligatory colon separator.

TL;DR it's a clever way to prevent appending a spurious trailing `:` in the (rare) case that the `PATH` variable is empty or unset.